# Error in getting data from list type using datastax

Tags: java, list, cassandra, datastax, cql3

I use `Cassandra 2.1.7` and `CQL3` for processing it.

I have a column of type `list<text>` in my table. I use `DataStax cassandra-driver-core-2.1.5` to read and write my data from `Cassandra`. While building of my query, I saw that the query that was building for my column `list<text>` was wrong.(I checked both the query's in `Datastax DevCenter`)

My code to build query.

```
Clause clause = null;
for (Entry<String, Object> val : conditionMap.entrySet()) {
    clause = QueryBuilder.eq("\"".concat(val.getKey()).concat("\""), val.getValue());
    where = where.and(clause);
}
```

The Query that build while I use the above method.

```
SELECT * FROM "ashokkeyspace"."table150" WHERE "id"=150 AND "listdata" =['apple'];
```

What query that I actually required.

```
SELECT * FROM "ashokkeyspace"."table150" WHERE "id"=150 AND "listdata" contains 'apple';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**: 2.1.7 dropped today

Looks like this is [supported](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/commit/48931452c71de42dedf3cee8b46a536dbf460239) as of the driver version [2.1.7](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-677).

Which is not yet officially released / [documented](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/whatsNew2.html).

But you can [build yourself](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver) or hold off until it is GA.

I recommend waiting before pushing to Prod because there are some known performance issues with the current 2.1.7 branch.

You want the new `ContainsClause` in the query builder.

For updates on release dates etc. see the [driver mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!forum/java-driver-user).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you say when will i get that 2.1.7 version.?

Comment: No hard date but you can follow the mailing list. If you're just in dev build it from source. If I were a betting man, I'd say it's a matter of a few weeks or less.